# closing console app by itself when shell connection closed

Tags: c#, shell, console

there are two application A and B
A is visual basic GUI application
B is C# console application and it calculates sum of two number which is supplied by A and send back to A using "writeline"

A executes B application via windows shell, A sends two parameters to B then catches the result.

Everything is fine but;
If I close the A accidiently , B is still living. How can I make the B closed  when the A closed.
I hope I can explained my issue :)
Thank you.

Comment: You're going to have to show your relevant code.  This is way too abstract for anyone to derive a useful answer.

Comment: Of all the different ways to implement process interop, using I/O direction is close to the worst one.  Use a local loopback socket or a named pipe or WCF.

Comment: Could you please point me to the right path /tutorial etc. An example would be great.. I am newbie btw..